# RDL file is not showing after restarting VS

Tags: visual-studio-2012, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I created rdl file in ssrs after restarting vs its not showing in solution explorer. But the file is present in folder

Comment: This generally happens when you save a report, but you don't save the project/solution that its a part of.

Answer (score 2):

Rdl files are not automatically recognized by Visual Studio, but you can add the rdl file manually via Shift+Alt+A in the solution explorer or via the GUI.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

First try to `'Clean'` and `'Rebuild'` your Report solution.

If that doesn't work since you said it exists in your folder you could manually add it.

Right Click on Reports folder > Add > Existing Item. See this image http://prntscr.com/8y3eyc